# How to display static page when updating website (ASP.NET 4.0)

Tags: asp.net, static, updating

When I update my website (I copy files via ftp) website doesn't work, so I want for that time display static page. What I do is I change the priority of default pages in IIS (7.5) and before coping new website files I past the first priority file, but it doesn't work - I've hoped that iis runs that file (display static page) and after coping new website files I remove first priority file and everything will be ok.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [app_offline.htm](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx) approach. Make sure you look [here if you are using asp.net mvc.](http://blog.kurtschindler.net/post/app_offlinehtm-gotchas-with-aspnet-mvc)